# How to upload/download document to Document Library via WEBSERVICES? Also set metadata

Tags: 2010, development, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, web-services

I want to retrieve a template document from a Document Libraries, in order to allow a user to edit it, and then upload it back again to the Document Library. I'll probably need to set some metadata info as well.
I know this can be done via COM, but how can this be done via webservices?

Comment: How to do it with COM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee956524.aspx#SP2010ClientOMOpenXml_Retrieving. Set Metadata: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/c772ae1e-ae90-4dd7-abd8-c459d9c43940

Answer (score 2):

Here are some C# code to upload and download files using webservice
I hope it's useful for you.

```
        string HttpUrl = "http://sharepointvm";
        string LibUrl = "http://sharepointvm/Shared Documents";
        string FileUrl = "C:/aaa.docx";
        string SaveFileName = "aaa.docx";
        #region uploadfiles
        try
        {
            //SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            //{
                SPSite site = new SPSite(HttpUrl);
                SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
                SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder(LibUrl);
                byte[] fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@FileUrl);
                //System.IO.FileInfo myfile = new System.IO.FileInfo(FileUrl);
                //byte[] fileContents = new byte[int.Parse(myfile.Length.ToString())];
                //FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(FileUrl);
                //int n = fs.Read(fileContents, 0, int.Parse(myfile.Length.ToString()));
                try
                {
                    folder.Files.Delete(SaveFileName);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
                    //return 4;
                }
                folder.Files.Add(SaveFileName, fileContents);
                //fs.Close();
                web.Dispose();
                site.Dispose();
           // });

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.Write(ex.Message.ToString());

        }
        #endregion

      #region downloadfile
        try
        {
            SPSite site1 = new SPSite(HttpUrl);
            SPWeb web1 = site1.RootWeb;
            SPList list = web1.Lists.TryGetList("Shared Documents");
            if (list == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Shared Documents not exist!");
                return;
            }
            foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
            {
                if (string.Equals(item["Name"], "aaa.docx"))
                {
                    //SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(1);
                    //SPFile file = item.File;
                    byte[] fileData = item.File.OpenBinary();
                    System.IO.FileStream fstream = System.IO.File.Create("C:\\MyDownloadFolder\\" + item["Name"]);
                    fstream.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.Write(ex.Message.ToString());

        }
        #endregion
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the copy.asmx web services, here's a good article by my colleague: http://ybbest.wordpress.com/2012/03/10/how-to-create-item-in-sharepoint2010-document-library-using-sharepoint-web-service/

Comment: Is it possible to download the documents from the sp 2010 site's splits attachments using spservices and copy.asmx